# How can I assert a struct conforms to a protocol?

Tags: swift, struct, xctest, swift-protocols, xctestcase

I have a test case that asserts a class conforms to a protocol.

```
        let sut = SomeClass()    
        ..........
        func test_some_class_conform_to_protocol() {
                XCTAssertTrue((sut as Any) is OverlayManagerType)

        }
```

I am trying to implement the same test with a `struct` that conforms to a protocol, however the test constantly fails.

Is it possible to achieve this?

**EDIT**

I have added my struct. I am following a TDD approach so there is no implementation as of yet.

```
protocol CountManagerType {

}

struct CountManager: CountManagerType {

}
```

My test is

```
    func test_count_manager_conform_to_protocol() {
            XCTAssertTrue((sut as Any) is CountManagerType)

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the test that fails? Then we can see what is actually going on.

Comment: I have updated my question :)

Comment: What is `sut`? I can't get `false` the way you're showing it.

Comment: Assuming that `sut` is an instance of `CountManager`, the assertion succeeds in my REPL.

Comment: Can't reproduce, possibly related to: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me, in the following example

```
protocol CountManagerType {
}
struct CountManager1: CountManagerType {
}
struct CountManager2 {
}

let c1 = CountManager1()
print(((c1 as Any) is CountManagerType)) // true
let c2 = CountManager2()
print(((c2 as Any) is CountManagerType)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code in a playground and it seems to be ok:

```
    import UIKit
    import XCTest

    protocol CountManagerType {

    }

    struct CountManager: CountManagerType {

    }

    struct CountManager1 {

    }

    class CountManagerTests: XCTestCase {
      override func setUp() {
          super.setUp()
      }

      func test_countmanager_conform_to_protocol() {
        XCTAssertTrue((CountManager() as Any) is CountManagerType)
      }

      func test_countmanager1_conform_to_protocol() {
        XCTAssertTrue((CountManager1() as Any) is CountManagerType)
      }
    }

    CountManagerTests.defaultTestSuite.run()
```